# MS Access: Prevent Combobox Control from adding new data to linked table

Tags: ms-access

MS Access (current version/365) -- Trying to build a simple invoicing solution. For the sake of this question, I have 2 tables:

- clients (ID [autoNumber], Name etc).

  - Example: ID = 1//name = "client 1"
  - Example: ID = 2//name = "client 2"
- items (ID [autoNumber], ClientID [FK to clients --> ID], itemName, etc.).

  - Example: ID = 1// clientID = 1 // name = "item 1 for client 1"

PK/FK/relationships established properly and clients are added in manually.

I want to build a form that has the capability to add in new items. Since it's difficult to identify clients by ID I'm hoping to (visually) link the clients and items table so I would have a dropdown (combobox) with the client name and then I could add in the new items associated with the client from the dropdown. There is no need to add in new client information at this stage, as that has already been added in in a previous step. Simply put, I want to select "client 1" from the dropdown, add a new item and it gets saved to the items table with client ID 1 (see above example) as:

- New item: ID = 2// clientID = 1 // name = "item 2 for client 1"

With the comboBox: The problem I have is that if I set the Control Source to be Client Name and the row source to be the appropriate column values from the clients table, if I add in a new item, Access will duplicate the client name under a new client ID. The item therefore gets saved as:

- New item: ID = 2// clientID = 3 // name = "item 2 for client 1"

Question: how on earth do I prevent Access from adding in a new (duplicate) client name with a new ID and just add the item to the existing client?
Thnx

Comment: What is the data entry form RecordSource - a query or SQL statement? Does it include the Clients table? If it does, I suspect you are binding textbox to wrong field. Items table should save ClientID, not ClientName. What is relationship of items to clients? Apparently clients can have multiple items but can items associate with multiple clients? If yes, then this is a many-to-many relationship and need a third "junction" table: ClientItems.

Comment: @June7 ControlSource is ClientName, RowSource is: SELECT dim_clients.Client_Name FROM dim_clients;  -- if I set it the ClientID then it will return the numeric IDs, which aren't particularly easy to work with.

Comment: No, I asked for form RecordSource. Combobox should be designed as described by @sheadhd answer. I suspect issue is combobox is bound to wrong field.

Comment: Ahhh gotcha. Yes, I was looking in the wrong place. Binding it to ID and using his solution (to only show the 2nd column [name]) works. Thanks. 
The form's source is: SELECT dim_clients.Client_Name, dim_invoiceItem.Client_ID, [...other cols]
FROM dim_clients INNER JOIN dim_invoiceItem ON dim_clients.[ID] = dim_invoiceItem.[Client_ID];

Comment: There is no need to include dim_Clients in the form RecordSource. This just contributed to confusion on which field to bind combobox to and caused the issue. Just bind to dim_invoiceitem table. Bind combobox to field in dim_invoiceitem - Client_ID. Also, **name** is a reserved word and should not use reserved words as object names. Also, camel case is easier to read than all one case: **InvoiceItem**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help your Client combo box and only seeing the ID, have the ClientID as the first column on the query builder and their name in the second column, then under the combobox `Properties` > `Format`, for `Column Count` put 2 (or 3 if you want to do First name last name) and for `Column Width`, put it as (for column count 2) 0;1.5 or (for column count 3), 0;1.5;1.5, this will hide the ID and only show the name.

Also what are the buttons on your form? You would need a 'New Record' button because it seems like you're just overwriting one record. Does your form show `Record: 1 of __` on the lower left side of your form?

[image: What's on the bottom left part of my form]

**Edit:**
What table did you want to collect all this data in? What is your forms `Record Source` set to? (to find this, click on the square in the top left corner of your form in Design View)

When the square is not clicked:[image]

When the square is clicked: [image]

Right-Click to open Form Properties and it should be under `Data`.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for that -- I do have the Record: 1 of __ on the side/bottom. Tried the solution you suggested, visually it works but it still tries to add in a new client rather than sticking to the one already in the database.

Comment: What is your Forms Record Source? What table do you want all of this information in?

Comment: I edited my response with images and further questions!

Comment: Got it, yes, sorry, you are right, I was binding the name column rather than the ID. So yes your suggestion works.